# Setting Word CustomTaskPane Width Dynamically

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, vsto

I have a VSTO custom task pane. In my code, I am setting the width to be 306 and it all appears correctly in Word 2010. Howevere, in Word 2013, some of the righhand side of the pane is not visble unless I manually drag to make it wider. Note this is the same PC so resolution shouldn't be an factor. I feel that if I just increase the width in code, i am not really addressing the real issue so want a way to set the width dynamically. Note the control is being docked against the right hand side

myPane.DockPosition = Office.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionRight;

so see no reason part of it should be hanging of the side of the screen. Besides, even if I dock it to the left, its still missing the righthand side of the pane.

Im not sure why I should even need to set a width in code, I thought it should pick up the size set in the USerControl designer, but if I don't set the size in code, the width is even smaller. I have played around with the autosize stuff, but got nowhere. I feel I am missing something obvious. Can anyone advise please?

Also as a side question, the custom control title height is much larger in Word 2013 than Word 2010. I can't see anywhere to change this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason might be because AFAIK the default resolution for Office 2013 for on screen view is 16:9 whereas the same for Office 2010 is 4:3.

I had encountered a similar situation (although for PowerPoint) where in the default resolution changes depending on whether it is Office 2010 or 2013.

So basically if you hard code the size of the task pane for 2010, I guess you will face what you are facing now(I faced it too!).

You might think of dynamically setting the width, but for that you would need to do two things

1. Check the Office version.This can be easily done as follows:

   ```
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application appVersion = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
   ```
2. Change the width dynamically in TaskPane.Designer.cs class in the InitializeComponent() method.

But the problem is that you can not add your custom code in the InitializeComponent() method, else that object will not be disposed properly even after uninstalling your add-in.
And an extra instance of the Word Process will appear in Task Manager.

So, I would suggest that you set the width as per what looks acceptable in Office 2013 and I hope that you won't need to drag the task-pane in Office 2010.

As far as your second question is concerned, I think that is the default behavior.

Cheers.